# Derivatives and Integrals of Polynomials and more.

Tags: integration, derivatives, polynomials, logarithms

I noticed that if I had a function $f(x)=x^n$ where $n$ is an integer, then $\lim_{m\to{n^+}}f^{(m)}(x)=n!$ where $f^{(m)}(x)$ is the $m$-th derivative.  Also, $$\lim_{m\to{n^-}}f^{(m)}(x)=\frac{(-1)^n\ln(x)}{n!}$$Where we have $m,n$ as integer numbers.

The limits I use in this question are not limits of the normal sense.  Instead, they are used to describe positives, negatives, and where it is heading.

$\lim_{m\to n^+}f^{(m)}(x)$ means that we are taking the $m^{th}$ derivative of $f(x)$ where we see $n$ is positive.

$\lim_{m\to n^-}f^{(m)}(x)$ means that we are taking the $m^{th}$ anti-derivative (it is negative) where we see $n$ is negative.

There is also a bridge between negative and positive $n$'s when $n$ is not an integer.

Which I though was pretty cool.

So I drew a little picture of what this was with an open circle in the middle for an unknown value at $\lim_{m\to{n}}f^{(m)}(x)$.

Basically, a number line for the powers of polynomials after the $n$-th derivative.  But I noticed something peculiar.

The integral of $\ln(x)$ looks a lot like $x^n$.  In fact, I deduced the following.

Let $g(x)=\ln(x)$$$g^{(-n)}(x)=\frac{x^n[\ln(x)-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1i]}{n!}$$where the $-n$-th derivative is the $n$-th anti-derivative.

So I got curious and wondered that upon taking derivatives of such a function, I would return back to polynomials in the form $x^n$, but what if I approached this from the other side?  Like we did with polynomials.

We could try to find a sort of bridge, where $n$ was non-integer like we did before.  Then we could try to approach our original point which I will call $g_0(x)$ from the sort of negative side, in a sense that it is opposite of the other side.

My assumption is that it would result in something along the lines of $h(x)\approx x^n\ln^2(x)$ with a lot of extra constants.

But I have no way of proving this because my formula for the $n^{th}$ anti-derivative does not work for negative numbers.

So I hope someone can find this interesting value.

Lastly, if this is so true, then I wondered the opposite.  Why would taking the derivative of a polynomial eventually reach $0$?  If my assumptions are true, the derivatives of a polynomial from the positive side should reach $e(x)=x^ne^x$ (hehe, get it? e comes before f?)

EDIT: It would actually result in something along the lines of $\frac{x^n}{\ln(x)}$

Also, if you can repeat my pattern and find some $h(x)$, then what about an $i(x)$?  Possibly a pattern I can use?

**December $25^{th}$**

I've also noted that the growth rates of $x^n\ln(x)$ exceed the growth rates of $x^n$.

If my assumptions are correct, then the growth rate keeps increasing.

**Again, December $25^{th}$**

I've also noticed that the growth rates of $x^n\ln(x)$ are less than the growth rates of $x^{n+a}$, meaning it is a sort of in-between function as far as growth rates.  Is there anything we can conclude on where $x^n\ln(x)$ could exist on a number line with $x^{+n}$ on the left and $x^{-n}$ on the right?

I also can't find what this value $a$ is.

It is clear $x^a\ne\ln(x)$, but for $0<a<1$, we have almost logarithmic growth rates.

Actually, I have just realized that $a=1$.

That is: $$\lim_{a\to1^-}x^{n+a}<<x^n\ln(x)<<x^{n+1}$$ If I am using my symbols correctly.

What does this mean?

What other interesting properties can we deduce?

Comment: Regarding your first line: I don't know very much about fractional derivatives, and correspondingly I'm not entirely sure what the first two limits truly mean. But I'd be surprised if the two limits given did not both converge to the same thing (probably $n!$), presuming one defines the correct idea of convergence for them.

Comment: What you're doing is relatively close to the idea behind Taylor polynomials. Are you familiar with them?

Comment: @ConMan Oh yeah, I am totally familiar with them.  However, I don't see how they answer my question.  I understand your point though with full meaning.  They don't appear to help me though.

Comment: How do you define a derivative of noninteger order?

Comment: @user26977 I can't.  But it seems obvious in the polynomial example on what I am doing.

Comment: @user26977 If you can assist in improving this question, I'd be appreciative.

Comment: I think that $\lim_{m->n+} f^{(m)}(x)$ actually means $f^{n}(x)$

Comment: @user26977 Use \to for arrows.  I can't define $f^{n}(x)$ where $f(x)=x^n$.  So I decided to use limits to describe the left/right side-ness of the derivative/integral.

Comment: I don't understand the first paragraph. Is it a limit of function? Then, how do you define $f^{(2.5)}(x)$?

Comment: @kamil09875 I used limits to *describe* my problem.  I can't think of any other way to put it.  Perhaps I will change it to only integer numbers.

Comment: Please then explain from where you got $\frac{(-1)^n\ln(x)}{n!}$. I can see that $$f^{(0)}=x^n,f^{(1)}=nx^{n-1},f^{(2)}=n(n-1)x^{n-2},...,f^{(n)}=n!,f^{(n+1)}=0,...$$ I can't see where you got $\ln$ from

Comment: @kamil09875 If you integrate $x^n$ where $n$ is a negative integer, that is what you get.  In that, we are using the definition where a negative derivative is an integral.

Comment: @kamil09875 The $\ln$ comes from $\int\frac1xdx=\ln(x)$

Comment: @kamil09875 Please feel free to shoot for an answer.  I don't want my bounty to go to waste and answers are apparently hard to come by.

Comment: @kamil09875 What you have done is basically what I have done.  That is why I have a limit from the positive and negative side, because, interestingly enough, they are different.

Comment: I will include everything in my answer when I come back home in few hours :) your questions make me think hard by the way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33442/discussion-between-simple-art-and-kamil09875).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Part 1

I will start with your first paragraph. You misunderstood the notation of limits. First of all, you don't need limits to express what you mean.

Write down the derivatives of $x^n$ for $n\geqslant0$:

$$\underbrace{x^n}_{0-\text{th}}, nx^{n-1},n(n-1)x^{n-1},...,\underbrace{n!}_{n-\text{th}},...$$

We conclude that the general form of this is

$$\frac{d^k}{dx^k}x^n=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}x^{n-k}$$ it implies that 
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}x^n=n!$$

Now consider the case for $n<0$. Of course we need then negative derivatives, exactly as you defined. To make things simpler we do a substitution $m=-n$ to have $m>0$. Then we need a general form of $$\int^k\frac{1}{x^m}\,dx^k$$ where $$\int^k\cdot \;dx^k=\underbrace{\iint\cdots\int}_{k\text{ times}}\cdot\;\underbrace{dx\,dx...dx}_{k\text{ times}}$$
means $k$-th integral (we will skip constants for simplicity). Then we write down few integrals

$$\frac{1}{x^m},\frac{-1}{(m-1)x^{m-1}},\frac{1}{(m-1)(m-2)x^{m-2}},...,\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{(m-1)!x},\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{(m-1)!}\ln(x)$$

it follows that $$\int^m\frac1{x^m}\,dx^m=\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{(m-1)!}\ln(x)$$

We can here define a function $$f(x,n)=x^n$$

and write down our two relations as
$$F(n)=\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}f(x,n)=\begin{cases}
\displaystyle x\mapsto n!&\text{for } n\geqslant 0\\[0.7em]
\displaystyle x\mapsto\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(-n-1)!}\ln(x) & \text{for } n< 0
\end{cases}\tag1$$

Of course this is function $\mathbb Z\to\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb R_+)$ but using analysis we are able to expand it to some bigger set. First note that we can expand $n!$ using $\Gamma(n+1)$ (by the way it is the only holomorphic logarithmically convex function satisfying $f(n+1)=n!$). The problem is when facing the $(-1)^{n+1}$ term. The only thing we can do is use the formula
$$(-1)^z=e^{\pi i z}=\cos(\pi z)+i\sin(\pi z)$$ so the function $(1)$ looks like

$$F(n)=\begin{cases}
\displaystyle x\mapsto\Gamma(n+1)&\text{for } n\geqslant 0\\[0.7em]
\displaystyle x\mapsto\frac{-\cos(\pi n)-i\sin(\pi n)}{\Gamma(-n)}\ln(x) & \text{for } n< 0
\end{cases}$$

It turns out that this function is not continuous<sup>1</sup> at $n=0$. Function $n!$ tends to $x\mapsto1$ whereas the second one tends to $x\mapsto0$:

$$\lim_{n\to0^-} F(n)=x\mapsto0 \quad\ne\quad x\mapsto1=\lim_{n\to0^+}F(n)$$

You can see the graph [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nvbczo5iuy) (move the slider $n$ - this is the argument, plot is the value). Keep in mind that I've deleted the imaginary part (by setting $i=0$) to make this visible, but it tends to $0$ anyway.

#### Part 2

Your formula is correct:

$$\int^n\ln(x)\,dx^n=\frac{x^n(\ln(x)-H_n)}{n!}\tag2$$

Nevertheless no element of this family of functions is close to $x^k$, you can see the plot [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eyvly7spzh).

**But you're right.** We are able to get back differentiating $\ln(x)$ $n$ times 
$$\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n-1)!}\ln(x)\quad\xrightarrow{\text{diferentiate }n\text{ times}}\quad\frac{1}{x^n}\tag3$$

See the pattern for $n$-th derivative of $\ln(x)$:

$$\ln(x),\frac1x,-\frac1{x^2},\frac{2}{x^3},-\frac{3}{x^4},...$$

The general form looks like the following

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\ln(x)=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(n-1)!}{x^n}$$

And plugging into $(3)$ we get

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\,\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n-1)!}\ln(x)=
\frac{{(-1)^{n+1}}}{{(n-1)!}}\cdot {(-1)^{n+1}}\frac{{(n-1)!}}{x^n}$$

#### Part 3

In part 2 I said that $(2)$ is not close to $x^k$. One may consider why is that if the limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\ln(n)-H_n\right)$$

converges to a constant. This constant is equal to $-\gamma$ where $\gamma$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). Of course it is because $$\ln(n)-H_n\not\equiv\ln(x)-H_n$$

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/20uxzc2qbt) is the plot of $(2)$ and $-\gamma x^n/n!$. A different thing is when you consider a function 
$$\frac{x^n(\ln(\color{red}{n})-H_\color{red}{n})}{n!}$$

it converges to $-\gamma x^n/n!$ as shown [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bglrmf09ct).

#### Part 4

You said that 
$$\lim_{a\to1^-}x^{n+a}\ll x^n\ln(x)\ll x^{n+1}$$

whereas I am pretty sure you meant 
$$x^{n+a}\prec x^n\ln(x)\prec x^{n+1}\tag4$$

where $\alpha\prec\beta\iff\alpha\in o(\beta)$. The notation $\gg$ and $\ll$ is used in approximations and physics and means "much larger/smaller". To check whether $x^{n+1}$ grows faster than $x^n\ln(x)$, consider a limit

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{x^n\ln(x)}=\infty$$

Indeed, we have $x^{n+1}\succ x^n\ln(x)$. Now the general form

$$L=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^{n+a}}{x^n\ln(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^a}{\ln(x)}$$

When $a=0$ we have of course $L=0$, but when $a>0$ we can use l'Hospital's rule to get

$$L=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{ax^{a-1}}{1/x}=\lim_{x\to\infty} ax^a=\infty$$

It means that only $a=0$ satisfies $(4)$.

---

<sup>1 By $F:\mathbb Z\to\mathcal C$ being continuous I mean that for $a,b$ such that $|a-b|$ is infinitesimal, the function $|F(a)-F(b)|$ is bounded by an infinitesimal.</sup>

Comment: Could you include a possibility where in **Part 2** we could find what should be the derivative assuming it doesn't reach $\frac1{x^n}$?  What I am asking is where we differentiate, for example, $x^{.5}$ and get $.5x^{-.5}$, making it continuous for anything except at $0$.  Could we do the same with the logarithm?

Comment: Could you also clarify my $n^{th}$ integral of the log?  I want to check my work.

Comment: @SimpleArt added general form of $\ln^{(n)}(x)$ but I can't understand your point of $(\sqrt x)'$.

Comment: While in part 1, we see that the derivative/integral is not continuous at $n=0$, we see it is continuous for all other $n$, even non-integer $n$.  I have also updated my question, you may see the edits at the bottom.

Comment: What I want to do is to make the $n^{th}$ integral of $\ln(x)$ continuous so that we can bypass the part where it becomes the form $x^n$.

Comment: @SimpleArt I will add this to my answer soon

Comment: To be honest, this is the first question that popped into my brain when I learned the integral of $1/x$.

Comment: @SimpleArt added part 3 where I am describing the polynomial approximation

Comment: In part 4, that was my bad.  Thank you for your answer.