# What is the $n^{th}$ derivative of $\log_x(e)$?

Tags: integration, derivatives, logarithms

I happened to stumble upon the integral of $\log_x(e)$, finding it to apparently be non-elementary.

So I had to see if I could discern a pattern by differentiating, much like finding the integral of $W(x)$.

$$f(x)=\log_x(e)=\frac1{\ln(x)}$$$$f'(x)=-\frac 1{x\ln(x)^2}$$$$f^{\prime\prime}(x)=\dfrac1{(\ln x)^2}+\dfrac1{2x^2(\ln x)^3}$$

Hopefully, there is a pattern that can be used to find $f^{(n)}$.

So please find $f^{(n)}$ and if we can, substitute $n=-1$ to find the integral of the function.

Comment: How did you conclude that $f^\prime(x)=x-\frac1{(\ln x)^2}$?

Comment: @MohsenShahriari Ooppsss... My mistake.

Comment: I think you (again) made a mistake while calculating $f^{\prime\prime}$!

Comment: @MohsenShahriari I'm sorry.  I taught myself calculus and I haven't had much practice.  Could you edit my question for me?

Comment: the correct calculation leads to $f^{\prime\prime}(x)=\dfrac1{(\ln x)^2}+\dfrac1{2x^2(\ln x)^3}$.

Comment: @MohsenShahriari Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33441/discussion-between-mohsen-shahriari-and-simple-art).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(BIG) HINT:

Notice:

$$f(x)=\log_x(e)=\frac{\ln(e)}{\ln(x)}=\frac{\log_e(e)}{\ln(x)}=\frac{\frac{\ln(e)}{\ln(e)}}{\ln(x)}=\frac{1}{\ln(x)}$$

So:

$$f^{(1)}(x)=-\frac{1}{x\ln^2(x)}$$
$$f^{(2)}(x)=\frac{2+\ln(x)}{x^2\ln^3(x)}$$
$$f^{(3)}(x)=-\frac{2\left(3\ln(x)\left(3+\ln(x)\right)\right)}{x^3\ln^4(x)}$$

So you've to show that:

$$\frac{\text{d}^n}{\text{d}x^n}\left[\frac{1}{\ln(x)}\right]=-\frac{n(1+n)\left(1+\lfloor{\frac{n-1}{2}}\rfloor\right)\ln^{(n)}(x)}{2\ln^2(x)}\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{for}\space n\in\mathbb{Z}\space\text{and}\space n\ge 0$$

And:

$$\frac{\text{d}^n}{\text{d}x^n}\left[\ln(x)\right]=\ln^{(n)}(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\epsilon^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(-1\right)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\ln\left(x+k\epsilon\right)\space\space\space\space\space\text{for}\space n\in\mathbb{Z}\space\text{and}\space n\ge 1$$

Notice for the last part that:

$$\frac{\text{d}^n}{\text{d}x^n}\left[\ln(x)\right]=\ln^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^{1+n}x^{-n}\Gamma(n)\space\space\space\space\space\text{for}\space n\in\mathbb{Z}\space\text{and}\space n> 0$$

Comment: I didn't understand the purpose of the last part.  I also want to see what substituting $n=-1$ will give me

Comment: @SimpleArt Like #kamil09875 said, I doesn't work like that!

Comment: Yes, but I just want to see what happens, perhaps for fun.

Comment: The first row is a complete redundant thing.. you could have just written the property of the "base - argument inversion" of the logarithm:

$$\log_b(x) = \frac{1}{\log_x(b)}$$

and make things easier..

Comment: @KimPeekII It's possible,but not essential! The function that I give you don't work for $n=-1$ because as I showed you it works for $n\ge 0$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: It doesn't work like that.

You cannot substitute $n=-1$ to get the integral because when finding the pattern, you take into account only derivatives. Nevertheless there exist a special function that is defined exactly as the anti-derivative of $1/\ln(x)$, namely $$\operatorname{li}(x)=\int_0^x\frac{1}{\ln(t)}\,dt$$

Comment: Yeah, I already knew about that.  But isn't there a thing where you can find integrals by taking the $-1^{st}$ derivative?

Comment: @SimpleArt You actually can do this! But.. the -1st derivative is defined as an integral, so actually this is the same thing :)

Comment: Wait, but what's the difference between the $-1^{st}$ derivative and finding a pattern for the $n^{th}$ derivative?

Comment: Is this like mathematical induction not working for negative numbers?  Where we prove it works for positive numbers without considering non-positives or non-integers?

Comment: @SimpleArt the only thing you can do is finding the pattern, when doing so you may face a new sequence or factorial. And when plugging $n=-1$ into it you may get $\infty/\infty$, $0/0$ or $a_{-1}$ where $a_n$ is your new sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The idea doesn't work, and you have an example at hand. The derivatives of $x^{-1}$ are all rational functions but it's integral is the logarithm, which cannot fit in this pattern.

Comment: Oh yeah, that is true.  Thank you.

Comment: I actually have a question concerning that specific integral found here for a bounty of 50 rep: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577505/derivatives-and-integrals-of-polynomials-and-more?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Write $s(n,k)$
for [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind).
Then
$$
f^{(n)}(x) =
\sum _{k=1}^{n}\frac{s\left( n,k \right) k!\, \left( 
-1 \right) ^{k}}{ \left( \ln  \left( x \right)  \right) ^{k+1}{x}^{n}}
$$
But you won't get any informaion trying to put $n=-1$ there.